# Applying patch to mahout

Tags: patch, mahout

I am trying to apply this patch https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAHOUT-944 to Mahout.

I've never applied patches before so this is new. Till now I haven't succeeded.

First of all, should I install all the patches or the most recent one?

I've tried installing using `patch -p0 < MAHOUT-944.patch` but I'm getting loads of errors like this: `1 out of 1 hunk FAILED`.

I've also tried applying the patch to various versions namely 0.5, 0.7 and the latest code from github. To which version should I apply the patch? Or is any version ok?

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This usually means you are not applying from the same base directory that the patch was made from, or, that it is a diff against a different version than you are applying it to.

Comment: how should I know in this case please?

Answer (score 0):

This patch is now in Mahout and will be available in Mahout 0.8